# Is thin layer chromatography suitable to characterize distillate samples?

Tags: chromatography

Would I be correct if I state: Thin layer chromatography (TLC) is a separation method for non-volatile mixtures. Because distillate samples are pure, this would not be appropriate.

I'm unsure and would like some insight into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is unnecessarily complicated and not easy to follow. You can use TLC as a quick way to assess the purity of a sample. It doesn't matter if your sample is a distillate or not. It only has to be non volatile as you said and soluble in some solvent or a mixture of solvents that can (the solvent/s) make it move on the TLC plate.

I assume you want to use distillation to separate a mixture and TLC in order to assess the purity of your fractions. Obviously TLC becomes an unsuitable method for low b.p. distillates